# tvOS UISearchController - how avoid automatic SearchBar & Keyboard hidden behavior when scroll?

Tags: uikit, uisearchbar, tvos, uisearchcontroller, uikeyboard

In my app I implemented UISearchController following the example project UIKitCatalog provided for Apple, here the code:

```swift
    /*
         A method demonstrating how to encapsulate a `UISearchController` for presentation in, for example, a `UITabBarController`
    */
    func packagedSearchController() -> UIViewController {
        // Load a `SearchResultsViewController` from its storyboard.
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewControllerSamples", bundle: nil)
        guard let searchResultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SearchResultsViewController.storyboardIdentifier) as? SearchResultsViewController else {
            fatalError("Unable to instatiate a SearchResultsViewController from the storyboard.")
        }

        /*
            Create a UISearchController, passing the `searchResultsController` to
            use to display search results.
        */
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. iceland)", comment: "")

        // Contain the `UISearchController` in a `UISearchContainerViewController`.
        let searchContainer = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
        searchContainer.title = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")

        // Finally contain the `UISearchContainerViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.
        let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchContainer)
        return searchNavigationController
    }
```

This implementation works great in my app, but has an automatic hidden behavior of SearchBar and Keyboard that a want to avoid, is this possible? and how?

Comment: did you find the solution ??

Comment: No, actually my tvOS application lives with this behavior.

Comment: For other pages, I am okay with the default behavior of tvOS. But for search page of my app, I don't want the search bar and keyboard to auto-hide. Youtube is doing that. their search bar and keyboard won't hide. I need the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

I search for this issue a lot, and all I found is to override the variable `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal: Bool` and make it returns `true`, but it did not work

The only successful solution to me was to force focus on search bar

```
class CustomeSearchController : UISearchController {
    
    override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment]{
        return [self.searchBar]
    }
        
    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        self.view.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
        self.view.updateFocusIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I hope this can help

Comment: but this will block other elements from getting focused right ??

Comment: @pgokul, unfortunately yes, so you need to check what is the next element in `didUpdateFocus` and pass it the `preferredFocusEnvironments` through a global variable in case you want to move to that element, anyway in my project I decided to go with the exiting behavior and let it hide when losing focus, because even with this solution you will face a few glitches and you need to fix more bugs

Comment: @AhmedAdnanQazzaz Hi Ahmed, nice to see you there :) 
how to avoid hiding Tabbar when scrolling on SearchVC when SearchController is included?